# Laravel update based on other value

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

How can I translate this to be used within the laravel query builder ?

MYSQL

```
update mytable
set val = val +1
where id = 1
```

In laravel

```
$res = DB::table('mytable')
->update(['val' => ?]);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
DB::table('mytable')->where('id',1)->increment('val');
```

the `increment` method accept as second parameter the amount to sum, if you need to do `val = val + 2` you can use `->increment('val', 2)`.

See this as reference: https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_increment

Comment: that's indeed, very eloquent ! 

I overlooked this in the api :X
thanks

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

In cases where you're doing a more complicated calculation than an increment, you can also do something like this:

```
DB::table('mytable')->where('id',1)->update(['val' => DB::raw('val * 3')]);
```

Be careful with `DB::raw` - it's not going to escape user input for you.